# Queria que cuando petara mi servidor me muestre un alert

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Aquí le digo que cuando guarde el objeto `persona` y no muestre `null`, me diga que esta guardado pero cuando muestre lo contrario, muestre el otro mensaje.

Aquí iría el service o el negocio donde **people** llamaría a la interface:

```
public String save(Personas person) {
       String mensaje;

       if(people.save(person) != null) {
           mensaje = "Se guardo correctamente";
       } else {
           mensaje = "Intente de nuevo";
       }

       return mensaje;

}
```

Aquí iria el controlador o la API para llamar al servicio:

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/persona", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
           @ResponseBody
           public String save(@RequestBody Personas person) {

            return serverPost.save(person);

           }
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Qué puedo hacer para que cuando me pete el servidor me muestre el mensaje: "**no se ha guardado**"?

Comment: Depende del tipo de error pero quizas puedas usar un try-catch en el save.

Comment: petara??? que es eso???

Comment: @Bryro *Petar* es una forma informal de decir *explotar* o *fallar*

Answer (score 1):

Puedes controlar mejor lo que devuelves usando un ResponseEntity:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/persona", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> save(@RequestBody Personas person) {
    try {
        String response=serverPost.save(person);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response); //HTTP Status 200
    catch (Exception e) {
        //HTTP Status 500
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body(e.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

Pero, si me permites el consejo, lo normal es devolver la entidad guardada:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/persona", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Personas> save(@RequestBody Personas person) {
    try {
        Personas response=serverPost.save(person);
        if (response != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response); //HTTP Status 200
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //HTTP Status 500
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

Teniendo el servicio así:

```
public String save(Personas person) {

    return people.save(person)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si he utilizado algo similar.

public String save(Personas person) {
   String mensaje = "";
   try {
       people.save(person);
             mensaje = "Se guardo correctamente";

```
    } catch(Exception exception) {

     mensaje = "Intente de nuevo";
    }
    return mensaje;
}
```